# How to combine the results of two SQL queries into one

Tags: php, mysql

I have two complicated queries that I would like to combine.

The first query returns these columns:

```
BOOKID
BOOKNAME
NUM_READ
DID_I_READ_IT
```

The second query returns these columns:

```
BOOKID
BOOKNAME
NUM_LIKES
DID_I_LIKE_IT
```

I would like to combine these into one result to get all columns as

```
BOOKID
BOOKNAME
NUM_ADDED
DID_I_ADD_IT
NUM_LIKEs
DID_I_LIKE_IT
```

BOOKS:

```
| ID | BOOKNAME |
|----|----------|
|  1 |    Book1 |
|  2 |    Book2 |
|  3 |    Book3 |
|  4 |    Book4 |
|  5 |    Book5 |
```

USERS_BOOKS:

```
| ID | USERID | BOOKID | STATUS |
|----|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 |    001 |      1 |   Read |
|  2 |    001 |      2 |   Read |
|  3 |    001 |      3 |  Added |
|  4 |    002 |      1 |  Added |
|  5 |    002 |      5 |  Added |
|  6 |    003 |      2 |   Read |
|  7 |    004 |      4 |   Read |
```

From [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9cff9/22) I can query a list of books, the number people who read them and whether I (user 001) read them or not.

```
     SELECT a.ID, a.BOOKNAME, a.NUM_READ, 
            CASE WHEN b.BOOKID IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS DID_I_READ_IT
       FROM (
             select BOOKS.ID, BOOKS.BOOKNAME, 
                    SUM(CASE WHEN USERS_BOOKS.STATUS='Read' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUM_READ
               from BOOKS
          LEFT JOIN USERS_BOOKS ON USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID = BOOKS.ID 
           GROUP BY BOOKS.ID
            ) AS a
  LEFT JOIN (
           select DISTINCT USERID, 
                           BOOKID
             FROM USERS_BOOKS
            WHERE STATUS = 'Read'
              AND USERID = '001'
            ) AS b ON a.ID = b.BOOKID
```

Result:

```
| ID | BOOKNAME| NUM_READ | DID_I_READ_IT|
|----|---------|----------|--------------|
|  1 |  BOOK1  |    1     |      Yes     |
|  2 |  BOOK2  |    2     |      Yes     |
|  3 |  BOOK3  |    0     |      No      |
|  4 |  BOOK4  |    1     |      No      |
|  5 |  BOOK5  |    0     |      No      |
```

There is another table for storing LIKES of books:

```
| ID | USERID | BOOKID | STATUS |
|----|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 |    001 |      1 |   Yes  |   //USER 001 likes BOOK 1
|  2 |    001 |      2 |   No   |   //USER 001 does not like BOOK 2
|  3 |    001 |      3 |   Yes  |
|  4 |    002 |      1 |   Yes  |   //USER 002 likes BOOK 1
|  5 |    002 |      5 |   No   |
|  6 |    003 |      2 |   Yes  |
|  7 |    004 |      4 |   No   |
```

From [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/641d9/1) I can query a list of books, the number people who liked them and whether I (user 001) liked them or not.

Result:

```
| ID | BOOKNAME| NUM_LIKES | DID_I_LIKE_IT|
|----|---------|-----------|--------------|
|  1 |  BOOK1  |     2     |      Yes     |
|  2 |  BOOK2  |     1     |      No      |
|  3 |  BOOK3  |     1     |      Yes     |
|  4 |  BOOK4  |     0     |      No      |
|  5 |  BOOK5  |     0     |      No      |
```

I want to combine these two queries into one so I want a list of books, the number of people who read them, the number of people who liked them, if I read them or not and if I liked them or not.

DESIRED RESULT:

```
| ID | BOOKNAME| NUM_READ | DID_I_READ_IT| NUM_LIKES | DID_I_LIKE_IT|
|----|---------|----------|--------------|-----------|--------------|
|  1 |  BOOK1  |    1     |      Yes     |     2     |      Yes     |
|  2 |  BOOK2  |    2     |      Yes     |     1     |      No      |
|  3 |  BOOK3  |    0     |      No      |     1     |      Yes     |
|  4 |  BOOK4  |    1     |      No      |     0     |      No      |
|  5 |  BOOK5  |    0     |      No      |     0     |      No      |
```

Of course there will be null values when e.g. someone liked a book that no one read or added to their list, or a book was never liked but read by many people.

Comment: But two people read book 1. I was one of them !?! Otherwise the number of likes makes no sense. And how can you not like a book you haven't read (unless it's anything by Jeffrey Archer)!?!?

Comment: And user 2 read book 5. What is going on here?

Comment: Check out my fiddle. NOTE: My schema AND data set vary slightly from yours... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b641/1

Comment: This code is much simpler, but I need to try it out if it works as good as Gordon's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to formulate your query using conditional aggregation.  This uses a subquery to follow the logic of your original queries:

```
 SELECT b.ID, b.BOOKNAME, r.NUM_READ, 
        (CASE WHEN r.IReadItFlag > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS DID_I_READ_IT,
        l.NUM_LIKED,
        (CASE WHEN l.ILikedItFlag > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS DID_I_LIKE_IT
 FROM books b LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT ub.bookid, SUM(ub.status = 'Read') AS NUM_READ,
              SUM(ub.status = 'Read' AND ub.userid = '001') as IReadItFlag
       FROM users_books ub
       GROUP BY ub.bookid
      ) r
      on b.id = r.bookid LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT ul.bookid, SUM(ul.liked = 'Yes') AS NUM_LIKED,
              SUM(ul.liked = 'Yes' AND ul.userid = '001') as ILikedItFlag
       FROM users_likes ul
       GROUP BY ul.bookid
      ) l
      on b.id = l.bookid;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68b7b1/10) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Hi Gordon. The first query doesn't bring anything near to what I want, the second query does not run due to an error.

Comment: @erdomester . . . What is the problem with the first version?

Comment: Here are the two tables: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68b7b1. Sometimes not even your first code runs but where are the like columns?

Comment: Thanks Gordon, nice job! This code is really complicated but thanks again